# Difference between pronunciations of 'ca' and 'ĉa'

Tags: pronunciation

I cannot tell how the pronunciations of 'ca' and 'ĉa' are different.
For me, they sound the same. (I am a native Korean speaker.)

```
Mi ne povas distingi la diferencon 'ĉa'r mi estas komen'ca'nto.
```

In the Wiktionary, the pronunciations of the above are t͡sa for 'ca' and t͡ʃa for ĉa which sound almost the same to me.

Answer (score 1):

The buzzing sounds in Esperanto, *ĉ, ĝ, ĵ, ŝ* and *z*, can be hard to distinguish one from another depending on one's native language.

When it comes to pronouciation of *ca* vs. *ĉa*, it helps to remember that the plain *s* in Esperanto is very sharp, like the s-es in the English word "issue". So *ca* has that shap *s* (tsa), while *ĉa* has the buzzing *s* (tsha).

Comment: You might also want to take a look at my answer to the question https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/107/how-does-esperanto-work-for-speakers-of-non-western-languages

Answer (score 1):

The sound starts with a ***t*** and then respectively ***sa*** ("ca") or ***ŝa*** ("ĉa").
The ***ŝa*** is a sharp open sound, like ***she*** in English. And ***sa*** would be like ***see*** in English.

Now by preceding the sounds with a ***t*** you might recognize the difference, at least in *pronouncing*. Recognizing a difference in one self pronouncing the sound can sometimes be corrected by recording ones own pronunciation. Reason: a human hears its own voice physically a bit differently.

Honestly the difference in sound might be much less, than the difference in articulation to form the sound. ***ŝ*** is blowing between open teeth, ***s*** is more closed. The IPA phonetic symbols are better explained by others.